# Retrieve full datetime from database and display in View in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to retrieve datetime from database and want to display in View. When I submitted the form, date stored in this format `2018-08-06 15:31:16.707` and I use some JQuery to get that date and it is currently showing in `Mon Aug 06 2018 15:31:16 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time) {}`. I want to show datetime exactly what is stored in database.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult _Update(EmpViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var Getadvert = context.Employee.Where(x => x.Position == model.Position).FirstOrDefault();             
            model.Updateddate = Getadvert.LastUpdatedDate;
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
    }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Updateddate, new { @id = "UpdatedDate" })
```

Script

```
 function UpdateModal() {
            var formdata = $('#Editform');
            var data = formd.serialize();         
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_Update", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {                                            
                        var src = data.Updateddate;
                        var src = src.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, '');
                        var dateupdated = new Date(parseInt(src));
                        $('#Updateddate').val(dateupdated);

                    }
                    else {
                        var message = data.message;
                        alert(message);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You have not shown what your `_Update()` function is or how your sending the data to the client.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I updated question and added in Controller. Please have a look.

Comment: Return a view model or an anonymous object containing just the properties you want, and make `Updateddate` a `string` and format it on the server as you want (using `.ToString("....")` and then all your need is `$('#Updateddate').val(data.Updateddate);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please add the the answer. I would love to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be formatted as shown in the database, then it is easiest to format it on the server and send it as a string. In your `JsonResult`, create an anonymous object containing only the properties you need in the view and return that, rather than your model

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _Update(EmpViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var Getadvert = context.Employee.Where(x => x.Position == model.Position).FirstOrDefault();
        // format the date          
        string date = Getadvert.LastUpdatedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
        return Json(new { success = true, date = date });
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "...." });
    }
}
```

and then in the script

```
function UpdateModal() {
    ....       
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {                                            
                $('#Updateddate').val(data.date);
            }
            else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is showing `No overload for method ToString takes 1 sarguments`

Comment: ?? - is `LastUpdatedDate` a `DateTime`

Comment: Yes Stephen. It is `DateTime` in database

Comment: Then what I have shown works fine. My best guess it that its really `DateTime?` (i.e. nullable), in which case you would need `Getadvert.LastUpdatedDate.Value.ToString(...)` (but you should also be checking for `null` as well)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. can you please guide me, I have more than one fields which I want to return. So can I use `return Json(new { model, success = true, date = date });`

Comment: No, but you could use `new { model = model, success = true, date = date }` and then `var x = data.model.someProperty;` in the script. But unless you want every property of `EmpViewModel`, then you should pass only the properties you want

Comment: Great solution. It is working like charm. You are real GURU Stephen.